# Springboot not connecting to mysql docker deployment

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker

i am trying to connect my springboot with mysql in docker, but it is always saying communication link failure. i have tried all the ways like docker-compose.yml and through command, created a common network and pointed to that, even after I'm getting the same. my jar having mysql-connector also in boot-INF folder. Kindly help me to solve the issue. below i will share the code

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  app-server:
    build:
      context: . # Use an image built from the specified dockerfile in the `polling-app-server` directory.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/employee_system?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: Ishel77@#
    networks:
      - backend
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: employee_system
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: Ishel77@#
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Ishel77@#
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend
volumes:
  db-data:

# Networks to be created to facilitate communication between containers
networks:
  backend:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM maslick/minimalka:jdk11

ADD target/*.jar employee-system.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "employee-system.jar"]
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/employee_system
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Ishel77@#
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Error

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at com.dailycodebuffer.Employee.EmployeeSystemApiApplication.main(EmployeeSystemApiApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[employee-system.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[employee-system.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[employee-system.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[employee-system.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you remove the `network` and `networks` thing and try? there should be a default one created

Comment: The Spring startup sequence prints out plain-text logs, but you attached a PNG-format image.  What produces this image file?  Can you [edit] the question to include the text of the Spring logs instead of that image?  If there's a "communication link failure" message, is there any information about why (you hint at a missing jar file, network issues, incorrect credentials)?

Comment: still the same @vladtkachuk, Can u give me ur mail id so that we can put a google meet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai)

Comment: I have tried this, Still the same @vladtkachuk

Comment: can you start the infra, wait until DB is up and try to run your Spring app on your host (not in docker)? use `localhost:3307` for DB url

Comment: 2022-07-12T09:56:20.370221Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011096] [Server] No data dictionary version number found.
employee-system-api-db-1          | 2022-07-12T09:56:20.370455Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
employee-system-api-db-1          | 2022-07-12T09:56:20.370716Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

I am getting this error when i removed MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: Ishel77@# in docker-compose.yml file

Comment: seems you have a DB issue and it causes the Spring error, explore the DB issue first

Comment: Try to add to your docker-compose.yml on db's section the following: "container_name: db". Aslo remove MYSQL_PASSWORD and MYSQL_USER since you are redefining "root" user and probably you are getting errors on db container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running your *docker-comnpose.yml* (only with **db** part) the following error occurs:

```
db_1  | 2022-07-12 11:25:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.29-1debian10 started.
db_1  | 2022-07-12 11:25:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db_1  | 2022-07-12 11:25:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.29-1debian10 started.
db_1  | 2022-07-12 11:25:04+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: MYSQL_USER="root", MYSQL_USER and MYSQL_PASSWORD are for configuring a regular user and cannot be used for the root user
db_1  |     Remove MYSQL_USER="root" and use one of the following to control the root user password:
db_1  |     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
db_1  |     - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
db_1  |     - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

Either remove MYSQL_USER and MYSQL_PASSWORD or change MYSQL_USER  to something that is not "root".

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: employee_system
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Ishel77@#
      MYSQL_USER: notroot
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: Ishel77@#
```